# How can I test if the boost shared memory object is removed or not?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory

I'm using boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object between the processes.

A process (server) creates a shared memory object, and other processes (clients) open that shared memory object. But, how can client processes determine if that shared memory object is removed by server process?

[As boost documentation states](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.sharedmemory.removing), when the shared memory is requested to be removed, it won't be deleted until all other references de-refer it. So, even if the server process (tries to) delete the shared memory object, that shared memory object is not deleted, and, so other client processes cannot know that was deleted or not.

I need this kind of delete-detection because of the reference caching. I mean, client processes stores the reference to the shared memory, and reuse it whenever needed. But, when the server process delete the shared memory and recreate one using the same name, I just want my client processes to detect this recreation and update the reference to the newly created shared memory object.

Comment: you can monitor the shared memory usage using unix ipcs command, though it might not help your cause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could include a flag in your shared memory object that indicates if your server process is still using it.

Set this flag to false before your server process attempts to delete the shared memory. When the client processes see that the flag is false they can close their references to the object.

Also, I don't think the server process will be permitted to recreate a shared object with the same name until it has been deleted, as I am sure the names must be unique.

Comment: But, server can re-create the shared memory using the same name because, when deletion is requested and still others are referencing it, it just change the internal object's name not to conflict with the original name. In my experiment on Win32, the paging file's name was changed to some random(?) name when deleted. Also, the boost documentation states (and requires) that recreation using the same name will be successful in any case.

Answer (score 3):

The command

```
ipcs -m
```

will display all existing shared memory segments. By *shmid* you should be able to identify your segment. There's also *nattch* column showing number of attached processes to the segment.